# It is possible to automatically update graphics when database changes?

Tags: mysql, r, statistics, business-intelligence

I'm working with R to create some graphs for my company and the next step is to get them online and dynamically updated.

The graphics are being generated through a connection to a MySQL database. That database get new entries every day and I would like that the graphics get updated as the database change.

It is possible to publish the graphics online and program a frequent update to them? Make the scripts run automatically and replace the file on the server...
 Maybe with some other tools or softwares...

Comment: Well, you can issue any system command you like via functions like `System` .   Or you could simply have a cron job that runs an R script which opens the latest data file, builds a graph, and writes that graph to the file (overwriting old version if desired).  Is that all you need to do?

Comment: Can't understand the first sentence... I think the cron job might resolve my problem, but I'm having problems programming it. I'm just trying to test it in my computer with a simple file, but I can't make it work. When we create the .bat file, the script file as to be in some specific folder?

Comment: I have to change the script I use in Rgui, to make it work in the Rterm? The result of trying to plot a graph in Rterm through my script is a black .png file...

Answer (score 0):

you can have a daemon/cron query your database for updates and then recreate and publish the graphics to the server.  If the database object is create from 1 table, you can look at using a `trigger` and `lib_mysqludf_sys sys_exec` to call an external script to recreate and publish the graphics.  Be aware of the security ramification when enabling/using `lib_mysqludf_sys`.  Scripts run from the `sys_exec` operates as the user running mysql db, so it can be maliciously use to destroy the db and if installed will be available to all users of the mysqldb.

Comment: I understood the idea, that sounds great. The rest I can't... sorry, I don't have too much knowledge in this area... Can you describe a simpler steps to do it?